# Powershell script not deleting child items

Tags: powershell

I am getting an error when running a PowerShell script. It is stating

> The item at Microsoft.Powershell.Core\FileSystem::\[path to directory] has children and the Recurse parameter was not specified.

In my PowerShell script I do have it specified. Is it in the wrong location?

```
# Add CmdletBinding to support -Verbose and -WhatIf 
[CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$True)]
param
(
# Mandatory parameter including a test that the folder exists       
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
[ValidateScript({Test-Path $_ -PathType 'Container'})] 
[string] 
$Path,

# Optional parameter with a default of 60
[int] 
$Age = 60   
)

# Identify the items, and loop around each one
Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Recurse -Force | where {$_.lastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).addDays(-$Age)} | ForEach-Object {

# display what is happening 
Write-Verbose "Deleting $_ [$($_.lastWriteTime)]"

# delete the item (whatif will do a dry run)
$_ | Remove-Item
}
```

Comment: Without testing myself to verify, I wonder if can you see if you're missing a closing curly bracket? Look at http://ss64.com/ps/foreach-object.html

Comment: Apolgies. There is one in the script. I did not paste it originally in my post.

Comment: Remove-item has a -recurse and -force. Have you tried them?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/3.0/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-item?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Thanks Tim. I added the `-recurse -force` to the `Remove-Item` but after running, I am still getting a confirm prompt asking if I want to delete the child items.

Comment: Have you tried `-Confirm:$false` instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
$_ | Remove-Item
```

While you've specified `-Recurse` and `-Force` on `Get-ChildItem`, that doesn't affect the later `Remove-Item` invocation. On `Get-ChildItem`, `-Force` just includes hidden and system items.

Normally, this would suppress the confirmation, and for me it does:

```
$_ | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force
```

Given that it's apparently still asking you for confirmation, it seems you have a `$ConfirmPreference` other than High. To get around that, you can add `-Confirm:$false` to the removal line to say "definitely do not ask for confirmation", or you can add this line further up in your cmdlet:

```
$ConfirmPreference = 'High'
```